Symfony and Fullcalendar how how to insert text into the calendar title if the text already has html tags
I have some information adbout university schedule in my database. The description of classes is stored in the database together with html tags. I want to display this schedule, but not remove the tags and not display them as text, but as a page structure.
script in my twig file:

        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.11/index.global.min.js'></script>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialView: 'listWeek',
                    events: {{ data|raw }}
                });
                calendar.render();
            });

        </script>

    public function getScheduleFromCalendar(LessonRepository $lessonRepository)
    {
        $groupSchedule = $lessonRepository->findGroupLessons('КН-1-4М');
        $lessonsList = [];
        foreach ($groupSchedule as $lesson) {
            if ($lesson->getLessonContent()) {
                $lessonsList[] = [
                    'start' => $lesson->getLessonStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'end' => $lesson->getLessonEnd()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'title' => $lesson->getLessonContent(),
                ];
            }
        }
        $data = json_encode($lessonsList);

        return $this->render('schedule/index.html.twig', compact('data'));
    }


How i can solve it? Thanks everybody!

It's a bit unclear, but I think you're asking how to make fullCalendar render your event titles as HTML rather than plain text? You'll need to utilise eventContent for that, I expect. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection for details.

    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'listWeek',
                events: {{ data|raw }},
                eventContent: function(info) {
                    return {
                        html: info.event.extendedProps.content
                    };
                }

            });
            calendar.render();
        });

    </script>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
